# Convert mm/dd/yyyy to MMMM dd, yyyy in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date-formatting

I have seen a lot of sources in converting a date to any format except converting it to **MMMM dd, yyyy**. Is there any way in MySQL that the returned date will be converted to **MMMM dd, yyyy** format?

**Sample Output:**

January 1, 2017

Comment: What do you mean by MMMM?

Comment: full  name of the month doesn't always have 4 characters..
so give an example for what you mean by MMMM

Comment: An edit has been made. Thank you for the suggestions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `date_format()` function can return the date pretty much however you want.

```
date_format(my_date_field, '%M %d, %Y')
```

More info on the function can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Comment: I replaced the dollar sign with percent sign and it worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's all available in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-07-03 22:00:00', '%M %d %Y');  -- July 03, 2017
```